# How to convert integer to model type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Here I am trying to show all shopping cart item along with there respective items in stock from table `Product` column `InStock`.
To get instock number for every item in cart i used foreach for every item and tried to add the number to cart.
Now, there is problem in line `cart.Add(item.InStock);`inside foreach saying `"Cannot convert from int? to eMedicine.Model.ViewModel.CartVM"`.
Below is my code

```
 public List<CartVM> ShoppingCartOrderList()
    {
        var cart = Session["cart"] as List<CartVM> ?? new List<CartVM>();
        var stockList = uow.Repository<Product>().GetAll().ToList();
        foreach (var item in stockList)
        {
            cart.Add(item.InStock); //error is in this line saying "Cannot convert from int? to eMedicine.Model.ViewModel.CartVM"
        }                       
        return cart;
    }
```

Below are model class

```
public class CartVM
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal? ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? Total { get { return Quantity * ProductPrice; } }
    public int? Instock { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
    public string ProdcutManufacturer { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProductComposition { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }

    public List<ProductGallery> ProductGalleries;
}

public partial class Product
{
    public int PId { get; set; }
    public string PName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IsPrescriptionRequired { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> InStock { get; set; }
    public string PImage { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IsNew { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductComposition { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `var cart = Session["cart"] as List<CartVM> ?? new List<CartVM>();` Why is your `cart` a `List` of something other than `int?` that you are trying to add `int?` to? You can't add apples to a carton of eggs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `cart` contains instance of `List<CartVM>`, you must use `new CarVM()` parameterless constructor to assign `Instock` property which has `Nullable<int>` type like this:

```
var cart = Session["cart"] as List<CartVM> ?? new List<CartVM>();
var stockList = uow.Repository<Product>().GetAll().ToList(); // the type is List<Product>

foreach (var item in stockList)
{
    cart.Add(new CartVM() 
             {
                 // other properties
                 Instock = item.InStock 
             });
}

return cart;
```

Note that you cannot assign `item` directly to `Add` method of `List<CartVM>` because `item` has type of `List<Product>`, hence you need to use `CartVM` instance and assign its properties from there.